# Disable CSS animations on Firefox

Tags: firefox, performance, css

I found CSS animations to be slow and most of the time useless. They make website feel heavy and laggy especially if I'm already using my CPU for other tasks.

Therefore, I would like to disable CSS animation on my browser to speed things up. The best would be a plugin like noscript or adblock where I can disable/enable for specific website.

Is there anything like that? I want snappy website :).

Comment: I've no idea whether this works in the latest version of Firefox, please let us know. [How to disable CSS transforms, transistions and animations](https://dev.webonomic.nl/how-to-disable-css-transforms-transistions-and-animations)

Comment: Thanks! I will check and wrap that in a plugin ASAP. I want a plugin to be able to switch it on/off easily.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I end up writing a Firefox extension based on @DavidPostill's comment.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/no-transition/

The extension let you globally disable/enable CSS transition and animation.

I hop it will be useful for others. The web feel fast again! <3

Comment: superb extension! Not as much speed improvement, as the background CPU consumption reduction, which was about 4 times in my case!

Comment: Works, glad someone is helping protect the future of the internet from distracting UI stimulus overload fever. I will keep this plugin enabled 99.999% of the time.

Answer (score 0):

For Firefox, you can create the userContent.css file and add to it some lines of code that disable CSS animations.

userContent.css is located in the folder named "chrome" where userChrome.css would be located, i.e.: Firefox_Profile_Folder\chrome\userChrome.css .

I tested it with the animation at the bottom of the page for each article, from theguardian.com - it was an animation with a vertical white gradient moving on a light gray background.

Tested on Firefox 104.0.2

I downloaded the add-on : Disable Transitions by UnshapelyMuskrat and un-zipped it.
I copied this code for the disable-transitions.css file:

```
* {
    animation-delay: initial !important;
    animation-direction: initial !important;
    animation-duration: initial !important;
    animation-fill-mode: initial !important;
    animation-iteration-count: initial !important;
    animation-name: initial !important;
    animation-play-state: initial !important;
    animation-timing-function: initial !important;
    animation: initial !important;

    -moz-animation-delay: initial !important;
    -moz-animation-delay: initial !important;
    -moz-animation-direction: initial !important;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: initial !important;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: initial !important;
    -moz-animation-name: initial !important;
    -moz-animation-play-state: initial !important;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: initial !important;
    -moz-animation: initial !important;

    -webkit-animation-delay: initial !important;
    -webkit-animation-delay: initial !important;
    -webkit-animation-direction: initial !important;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: initial !important;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: initial !important;
    -webkit-animation-name: initial !important;
    -webkit-animation-play-state: initial !important;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: initial !important;
    -webkit-animation: initial !important;

    transition-delay: initial !important;
    transition-duration: initial !important;
    transition-property: initial !important;
    transition-timing-function: initial !important;
    transition: initial !important;

    -moz-transition-delay: initial !important;
    -moz-transition-duration: initial !important;
    -moz-transition-property: initial !important;
    -moz-transition-timing-function: initial !important;
    -moz-transition: initial !important;

    -webkit-transition-delay: initial !important;
    -webkit-transition-duration: initial !important;
    -webkit-transition-property: initial !important;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: initial !important;
    -webkit-transition: initial !important;
}
```